# $(2,1+\sqrt{-5}), (1-\sqrt{-5},2)$ generate the $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$-module $\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle \times \langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Ok, boring question here (I guess, at least). Let $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Let $M=\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle$ the $R$-module generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$. I am asked to show that $M \times M = \langle (2,1+\sqrt{-5}), (1-\sqrt{-5},2) \rangle$, i.e. that $M \times M$ is generated by the two elements $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$, and that $M \times M$ is free.

I was able to prove that $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$ are linearly independent, but I can't find any way to show that they generate the whole $M \times M$ module.

I tried to proceed as follows: for any $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h \in \mathbb Z$, I must find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$\big( 2(a+b\sqrt{-5})+(1-\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5}), 2(e+f\sqrt{-5})+(1-\sqrt{-5})(g+h\sqrt{-5}) \big)$$
$$=$$
$$\big( 2(\alpha+\beta\sqrt{-5})+(1-\sqrt{-5})(\gamma+\delta\sqrt{-5}), (1+\sqrt{-5})(\alpha+\beta\sqrt{-5})+2(\gamma+\delta\sqrt{-5}) \big).$$

After some computations, this lead me to 
$$\big( 2a+c+5d+(2b+d-c)\sqrt{-5}, 2e+g+5h+(2f+h-g)\sqrt{-5} \big)$$
$$=$$
$$\big( 2\alpha + \gamma + 5\delta+(2\beta+\delta-\gamma)\sqrt{-5}, 2\gamma + \alpha - 5\beta + (2\delta+\beta+\alpha)\sqrt{-5}) \big),$$

which means that I have to solve the following system:
$$
\begin{cases}
2\alpha + \gamma + 5\delta= 2a+c+5d\\
2\beta+\delta-\gamma= 2b+d-c\\
2\gamma + \alpha - 5\beta= 2e+g+5h\\
2\delta+\beta+\alpha= 2f+h-g\\
\end{cases}
$$

and I don't know how to go on.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: uuuummm .. how can two ideals of $R$ be linearly independants ?? I don't get exactly what $\langle M_1,M_2\rangle$ is. Is it the $R$-module generated by the couples $(m_1,m_2)$ for $m_i \in M_i$ ?

Comment: I am really not into number theory, so I might be wrong, but I am pretty sure that who wrote the exercise meant that $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is just an element of $M \times M$, and the same for $(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$. Just like $(13\pi, 7\sqrt{51})$ is a vector of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: oooh the ambiguity ! I didn't even think of that you're probably right haha.

Comment: note: I edited the question to make it more clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \langle(2,1+\sqrt{-5}),(1-\sqrt{-5},2)\rangle$.

As you've probably seen, $2 \times 2 - (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}) = -2 \neq 0$ so $I$ is a free $R$-module of rank $2$, and we even have an $R$-basis of $I$.

More importantly this calculation also shows that $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ are in $I$ (just do the combination that cancels each component in the obvious way).

Then it's immediate to see that $(0,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-5},0)$ are also in $I$, and finally that $M \times M \subset I$.

The other inclusion is obvious : since $2,1+\sqrt{-5},1-\sqrt{-5} \in M$, $I \subset M \times M$.

Hence $M \times M$ is the free $R$-module of rank $2$ generated by $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$

Comment: That's totally awesome! Thank you so much!
Just one question: I was able to prove that the two "vectors" are linearly independent, but I did it by hand, so it's really long, boring and most important non-elegant at all. I would like to understand better your method...you are just calculating the determinant, right? I know that it works with vector spaces...does it work with modules as well? maybe I should take a look to the proof about vector spaces and try to convert it...

Comment: If you search for a $k$ such that $(2,1+\sqrt{-5}) = k(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$ you end up with $0 = k-k = (2/(1-\sqrt{-5})) - ((1+\sqrt{-5})/2) = -2/(2(1-\sqrt{-5}))$, contradiction. In fact this shows that they stay independant over any field extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, like $\Bbb C$ for example. This is more general, the determinant method works with a family of $n$ vectors in a vector space of dimension $n$. Had the determinant been $0$, then we would have had to check over which field is the relation, it can happen that the dependance is over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ but not over $\Bbb Q$